# mysql unique columns not accepting null value

Tags: mysql

I have two columns unique email and serverip, but when i try to insert data in email only without serverip it throws a error `Duplicate entry '' for 'serverip'`

I tried making email and serverip DEFAULT NULL but it still throwing me the error if i try to insert only into one colum email.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `email` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cname` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `serverip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serverip` (`serverip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: `serverip` is unique.  `NULL` is a value.  Two `NULL` values is *not* unique.

Comment: @JeremyMiller ok i made email to NOT NULL and serverip to DEFAULT NULL, now when i try to insert data into only email it throws the error duplicate entry on serverip.. can u help?

Comment: You are distracted.  What I see lies in `UNIQUE KEY serverip (serverip)`

Comment: Remove the UNIQUE constraint from serverip

Comment: you should create the `index`

Comment: @JeremyMiller my serverip must be unique only if i insert something in that column or otherwise it should take other insertion leaving the serverip blank. how can i do it?

Comment: Compound Key. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *made email to NOT NULL and serverip to DEFAULT NULL, now when i try to insert data into only email it throws the error duplicate entry on serverip*

It is because the `serverip` field is defined to hold a `default null`.
Apart from this, the field is also `unique`.

A `unique` field can only have a specific value once for its life.

And when you avoid the field in an `insert` statement, the `default` clause will come into picture and the engine will try to assign the `default` value which is `null` for the field.

But as the field already has a `NULL` entry in the table, it can't accept another same value for it has to maintain `unique`ness on the `serverip` field data.

And hence you got the error.

And if you still want to maintain `unique`ness on the `serverip` data, by some means, to allow blanks, you have to

- Remove `unique` constraint on it.
- Define a `before insert/update trigger` to check if such value
  already present or not.
- If blank, accept it otherwise restrict it on duplicate.

Comment: thanks for the information. is there any way to solve it? or what is my alternative way to achieve this? I want o insert email and serverip as unique but sometime I want to insert only email not the both.

Comment: I gave some suggestion in the answer. Try triggers to handle it. Or you can also define composite key on both email and serverip columns. This option is only useful if you want to add more ip's per email address.